# Django filter on DRF with exact match of any field

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using `django filter` on DRF with following model.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    passport_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    nic_driving_license = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I'm sending either `passport_no` or `nic_driving_license` from the FE as `id_no=<value>`. How can I specify the `filterset_fields` to look for exact match on either of above fields? Following is not working since I think it does an **AND** match.

```
filterset_fields = {
    'passport_no': ['exact'],
    'nic_driving_license': ['exact']
}
```

Comment: `OR` is not supported by `django-filter` out of the box. You may want to implement custom class inheriting from`FilterSet ` that implements a method returning a queryset. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the suggestion of @wiaterb I was able to do this exactly. Posting the solution to help others.
Note: No need to specify `filterset_fields`.

`views.py`

```
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Person


class IDFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id_no = django_filters.CharFilter(method='search_by_id', label='Search By ID')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['id_no']

    def search_by_id(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(passport_no=value) | Q(nic_driving_license=value)
        )


class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filterset_class = IDFilter
```